# Cakephp installing Bake on Centos production server

Tags: php, cakephp, centos, cakephp-2.0, cake-console

I'm about to include `cake` in my path on my Centos production server and start using `cake` commands from the command line to manage my ACL framework. I looked around for notes on the potential hazards of having `cake bake` and also `cake acl` available on the server and there is not much literature on using these tools in production. My three main concerns are as followed.

1: Does running a `cake` command effect performance or latency times for anyone viewing the site either while the `cake` command is run or after it is run? Obviously running scripts affects performance, but is this a performance hit that people viewing the site would notice?

2: Are there any security issues associated with `cake` being installed on the server?

3: Does including `cake` in the centos path cause any issues,  and should such a path edit be placed in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file? Cake's docs says to use either. Which is preferred?

Any additional information on using `cake` commands from the centos command line would be of great help. Thank you to anyone who has input regarding these questions.

Comment: This answers part 3 of my question to anyone that might need this: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: This information is also helpful towards answering this question: http://metazentech.blogspot.com/2011/12/getting-cakephp-bake-to-work-in-linux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Running cake alone wont do much, it highly depends on what shell you exactly run. If you for example use the migrations plugin for an app or another shell that is doing a lot in the background it is logical that it will effect the performance of the site. There is an unix command called "[nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29)" you can use to limit the cpu usage.

2) Depends on who you allow to use it mostly and what cake shells you're running with it. If you execute malicious code or an user who is not allowed running a script that might blow up some data... The core code itself is pretty solid.

3) I guess you've got [the answer](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) already in the comments. I would say its a matter or personal preference and taste but I'm not a linux fanboy and use it only when I have to, so there might be a better answer for that point.